# Checkbox variable outside of function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to coding (trying to learn) and I cant figure out how to get the var of the check box value outside of the function.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var quantity= parseInt($('#phones').val());

  $("#check1 input:checkbox").change(function() {
      var feature = 0;
      $("#check1 input:checkbox").each(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              feature += parseInt($(this).prop('value'));
          }
      });

  });

  var grand = feature * (quantity * Number ('0.1'))

  var total = quantity + grand

});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="phones" type="numerical" value="0" style="text-align: right"/>

<div id="check1">

<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Any special reason you can't keep all your variables and math within the event handler?

Comment: There are more than one checkbox and each checkbox's default value is 0 and when it is checked = 1. the value of the checkbox is multiplied with an equation (each checkbox has a different equation) and the result of all checkboxes and quantity of products is added up as a grand total.

Comment: parseInt('0.1') is 0. So grand is 0 and total = quantity

Comment: Sorry that was suppose to be Number ('0.1'). I have corrected that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getResult(feature, phones) {
  if (feature <= 0 || phones <= 0) {
    return 'Error...., enter the number of phones and check some checkbox';
  }

  return (feature * (+phones * 0.1)) + +phones;
}

function getFeature() {
  var feature = 0;

  $('#check1 input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    feature += +$(this).prop('value') || 1; 
  });

  return feature;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $phones = $('#phones'),
      $result = $('#result');

  $("#check1 input:checkbox").change(function() {
    $result.html(getResult(getFeature(), $phones.val()));
  });

  $("#phones").keyup(function() {
    $result.html(getResult(getFeature(),  $phones.val()));
  });
});
```

Demo: [http://jsbin.com/hivilu/2/](http://jsbin.com/hivilu/2/edit?js,output)